# Microsoft Graph returns 403 Forbidden on a second attempt to create a subscribtion

Tags: java, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-exchange

I did manage to subscribe to Microsoft Graph push notifications for one time for the following resources:

- me/calendars;
- me/calendars/{id}/events

However, when I try to do the same now, I get:

> 403 Forbidden https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7afa93f6-f616-4ea7-9bbe-c977ffd1e239",
      "date": "2017-07-14T16:23:35"
    }
  }
}
```

My request looks as follows:

```
{
  "resource": "me/calendars/{ID}/events",
  "notificationUrl": "https://myapp/MyService/notifications/",
  "clientState": null,
  "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
  "expirationDateTime": "2017-07-17T14:53:33Z"
}
```

Docs that I use:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks

I suspect Microsoft Graph to give such an error because of the fact that there is a currently working subscription after me first time subscribing. However, when I worked with outlook API, I could get as many subscriptions as I wanted to.

The question is, does Graph API support multiple subscriptions for one resource and if yes, what can be the cause of the *403 Forbidden* in such a case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Microsoft Graph Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Microsoft graph supports multiple subscription for one resource. We investigated this request. Exchange is denying the access. Please make sure you are using right credentials. Please reactive this issue if necessary. Thank you.

Comment: I have some ideas regarding this one... Just need to check that.

Answer (score 1):

The error was fixed after adding additional *scopes*.

**Before:**

```
Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Files.ReadWrite.All User.Read openid offline_access profile
```

**After:**

```
Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Calendars.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All User.Read openid offline_access profile
```

Comment: Why do you need Calendars.Read, when you have Calendars.ReadWrite? Isn't the first included in the last?